# Using functools.wraps with a logging decorator

Tags: python, logging

I'm trying to write a simple decorator that logs a given statement before calling the decorated function. The logged statements should both appear to come from the same function, which I thought was the purpose of functools.wraps().

Why does the following code:

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(funcName)20s - %(message)s')

from functools import wraps

def log_and_call(statement):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logging.info(statement)            
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator


@log_and_call("This should be logged by 'decorated_function'")
def decorated_function():
    logging.info('I ran')

decorated_function()
```

result in log statements like:

```
             wrapper - This should be logged by 'decorated_function'
  decorated_function - I ran
```

I thought the call to wraps would rename wrapper with decorated_function's name.

I'm using python 2.7.1.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Unfortunately `logging` uses the function code object to infer the name. You could work around this by using the [`extra`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.debug) keyword argument to specify some additional attributes for the record, which you could then use during formatting. You could do something like:

```
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.DEBUG,
    format='%(real_func_name)20s - %(message)s',
)

...

logging.info(statement, extra={'real_func_name': func.__name__})
```

The only downside to this approach is that you have to pass in the `extra` dictionary every time. To avoid that you could use a custom formatter and have it override `funcName`:

```
import logging
from functools import wraps

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Custom formatter, overrides funcName with value of name_override if it exists"""
    def format(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'name_override'):
            record.funcName = record.name_override
        return super(CustomFormatter, self).format(record)

# setup logger and handler
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter('%(funcName)20s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

def log_and_call(statement):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # set name_override to func.__name__
            logger.info(statement, extra={'name_override': func.__name__})
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@log_and_call("This should be logged by 'decorated_function'")
def decorated_function():
    logger.info('I ran')

decorated_function()
```

Which does what you want:

```
% python logging_test.py
  decorated_function - This should be logged by 'decorated_function'
  decorated_function - I ran
```

Comment: Is there any way to do the same without passing the statement all the time. means I just want to use logger.info('test {}', 123) in my code but it automatically append an extra dict. now I use your idea . like def log_and_call(statement, level): ....and def test(st, level):@ log_and_call() def api():pass api() .  and use like logger.debug('test {}'.format(123), 'debug'). Its working is there any better method.

Answer (score 6):

I have found in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logrecord-objects) how it can be done, just add this code to your decorator:

```
def log_and_call(statement):        
    def decorator(func):
        old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

        def record_factory(*args, **kwargs):
            record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
            record.funcName = func.__name__
            return record

        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logging.setLogRecordFactory(record_factory)
            logging.info(statement)
            logging.setLogRecordFactory(old_factory)
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

or instead of functools.wrap use this decorator:

```
def log_wrapper(func_overrider):
    old_factory = logging.getLogRecordFactory()

    def new_factory(*args, **kwargs):
        record = old_factory(*args, **kwargs)
        record.funcName = func_overrider.__name__
        return record

    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            logging.setLogRecordFactory(new_factory)
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            logging.setLogRecordFactory(old_factory)
            return result

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

Comment: The use of a temporary LogRecordFactory works, although I haven't tested your exact code. Is there any way to get record.lineno to show correctly as well? This might need `inspect`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike you may suspect, the logging.*functions* do no use the __name__ attribute. This implies using `@wraps` (or setting the __name__ of the wrapper manually) does not work!

Instead, the show that name, the call-frame is examined. It contains a list of *code*-items (basically the stack). There the function name read, as well as the filename and line-number. When using a logging-decorator, the wrapper-name is always *printed*, as it is the one that calls log.

BTW. The logging.**level**() functions all call `logging._log(*level*, ...)`, which calls other (log) functions as well. Which all end-up on the stack. To prevent those log-functions are shown,  the list of frames is searched for the first (*lowest*) function which filename is not part of 'logging'. That should be the real function to log: the one calling logger.*func*().

Regrettably, it is `wrapper`.

It would, however, be possible to use a log-decorator: when it is part of the logging source file. But there is none (yet)

Comment: So I guess this means that it's unlikely that Python 2.7.x series would ever fix this, right?

Comment: It's open-source, so make a patch! The code is there, readable and not to complex ... And as far I remember 2.7 and 3.* is almost the same here. So don't wait for 3

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple generic decorator:

```
def logged(fn):
    from functools import wraps
    from datetime import datetime,timezone
    @wraps(fn)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        run_time=datetime.now(timezone.utc)
        result=fn(*args,**kwargs)
        print('{0} called at {1}'.format(fn.__name__,run_time))
        return result
    return inner
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's 2022 and this is still difficult.

Here's a complete example with correct filename and line number as well in case it's desired. This is adapted from @zeekay's answer.

```py
from inspect import getframeinfo, stack
import logging
from functools import wraps

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """Custom formatter, overrides funcName with value of name_override if it exists"""
    def format(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'name_override'):
            record.funcName = record.name_override
        if hasattr(record, 'file_override'):
            record.filename = record.file_override
        if hasattr(record, 'line_override'):
            record.lineno= record.line_override
        return super(CustomFormatter, self).format(record)

# setup logger and handler
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
handler = logging.StreamHandler()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(CustomFormatter('%(asctime)s - %(filename)s:%(lineno)s - %(funcName)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'))
logger.addHandler(handler)

def log_and_call(statement):
    def decorator(func):
        caller = getframeinfo(stack()[1][0])
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # set name_override to func.__name__
            logger.info(statement, extra={
                'name_override': func.__name__,
                'file_override': os.path.basename(caller.filename),
                'line_override': caller.lineno
                })
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@log_and_call("This should be logged by 'decorated_function'")
def decorated_function():  # <- the logging in the wrapped function will point to/log this line for lineno.
    logger.info('I ran')

decorated_function()
```

Defining `caller` before the `wrapper` function will correctly get the calling function's (i.e. `decorated_function`) filename and line number.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect that the logging module uses the __name__ attribute on a function object. That doesn't typically change even if you assign the function to another name...you'd see the same results doing something like:

```
def foo()
  logging.info("in foo")
bar = foo
bar()
```

You will get `foo - in foo`, not `bar - in foo` when you call bar.

Decorators are doing something similar under the hood.

Comment: Did you read anything about `wraps` before you posted this? It's entire purpose is to do exactly what you're saying it doesn't do.