# Python decorator as class member

Tags: python, decorator

I want to create a decorator for class functions that will produce logging messages at the start and end of the functions with information specific to the class instance running the function. I've tried doing this by creating the decorator as class member, but that doesn't work because the decorator expects the function as the first argument, but as a class method it needs to be `self`. Here is what I've written so far that doesn't work:

```
import functools, logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s:%(message)s', 
                            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        
    def log(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper_log(*args, **kwargs):
            logging.info(f"Started (instance {self.bar})")
            func(*args, **kwargs)
            logging.info(f"Finished (instance {self.bar}")
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper_log
        
    @log
    def test(self, a, b, c):
        pass
    
foo = Foo("bar")
foo.test(1, "b", [3, 4])
```

I can't move it out of the class and pass the class instance as an argument by decorating the class functions with `@log(self)` because `self` doesn't exist outside of the functions. How can I do this?

Comment: you are calling `func` twice - between the logs and with return. ~Why don't you move the logging calls outside of the `wrapper_log` function? I've done something similar which works. Although I've created a decorator without the functool.wraps()~. You probably want to save the return value and return that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the decorator outside the class and it will work just fine, but you need to refer explicitly to `self` in the wrapper signature.

The reason why this work is because all the definitions inside a function are evaluated only when the function is called. By the time the function `test` is called it has already been bounded to the instance and `self` will exists in its namespace.

```
import functools, logging

logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(funcName)s:%(message)s', 
                            datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S %p',
                            level=logging.DEBUG)

def log(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper_log(self, *args, **kwargs):
        logging.info(f"Started (instance {self.bar})")
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        logging.info(f"Finished (instance {self.bar}")
        return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper_log

class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        
    @log
    def test(self, a, b, c):
        pass
    
foo = Foo("bar")
foo.test(1, "b", [3, 4])
```

This will output

```
2020-10-05 11:31:20 PM - INFO - wrapper_log:Started (instance bar)
2020-10-05 11:31:20 PM - INFO - wrapper_log:Finished (instance bar
```

Comment: Thanks! I notice that the %(funcName) in the logging format is showing the name of the wrapper function, not the function from the class. I thought @functools.wraps(func) was supposed to preserve the original function's metadata for introspection. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: It's a bug of the logging module which uses the wrong name. The `wraps` function does its job. Please refer to this answer for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003898/using-functools-wraps-with-a-logging-decorator