# Python loggers not working after changing name

Tags: python, logging

I have a library in which I am creating the logger as a class attribute

The entry point class accepts handlers and applies adds them to the root logger:

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, handlers):
        for hdlr in handlers:
            logging.root.addHandler(hdlr)
```

Now this works if my internal classes initialise the logger like this:

```
class Event(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self._log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

However, this is no use as the **logs don't show the class name**. So I tried this:

```
class Event(abc.ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        self._log = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)
```

This would allow me to see the class name in the logs for the subclasses.

*Alas, this **doesn't** work*. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53250066) answer will not work for me probably, since `Event` objects are constructed after the `__init__` method of `Parser` is finished (and hence the loggers they use), *so `logging.root.manager.loggerDict` would still be empty*.

This doesn't work either

```
class Parser:
    def __init__(self, handlers):
        for hdlr in handlers:
            logging.root.addHandler(hdlr)
            for cls in Event.__subclasses__():
                logging.getLogger(cls.__name__).addHandler(handler)
```

**EDIT**:
This is my `__init__.py` at the package root. I doubt it is any use. But I don't know what else to give, I have already provided all the logging code above.

```
"""
Attributions:
    Logger decorators:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7004565
"""

import functools
import logging

class WrapperFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        if hasattr(record, "name_override"):
            record.funcName = record.name_override
        return super().format(record)


logfmt = "[%(levelname)s] %(name)s <%(module)s.%(funcName)s>  %(message)s"
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.NullHandler()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(WrapperFormatter(logfmt))
logger.addHandler(handler)


def called(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*a, **kw):
        log = "called"
        if a:
            log += f" with {(repr(arg) for arg in a)}"
        logger.debug(log, extra={"name_override": func.__name__})
        return func(*a, **kw)
    return wrapper
```

I have a feeling that I am doing this the wrong way.

Comment: I can't tell from your question what it is that doesn't work after the name change. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @blues I have added code from `__init__.py` at package root. I hope it helps