# python decorator to print return values

Tags: python-3.x, return, decorator

This question concerns Python 3.
Is there a way to make a decorator print the return values to any function?  This question [Decorator to print function call details - parameters names and effective values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200270/decorator-to-print-function-call-details-parameters-names-and-effective-values) will print all the values you pass to a function.  Is there a way to make a decorator that prints the values of whatever the function returns regardless of whether it returns a single value or many?

So that if you were to run this:

```
multiply(subtract(add(1,2),add(3,4)),9)
```

with all of the functions decorated with @superecho it would log:

```
function call add() 1,2
function add() returns 3
function call add() 3,4
function add() returns 7
function call subtract() 3 7
function subtract() returns -4
function call multiply() -4 9
function multiply() returns -36
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import functools

def monitor_results(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
        print('function call ' + func.__name__ + '()')
        retval = func(*func_args,**func_kwargs)
        print('function ' + func.__name__ + '() returns ' + repr(retval))
        return retval
    return wrapper

@monitor_results
def foo():
    return 7

foo()
# prints:
#     function call foo()
#     function foo() returns 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this suit your needs?

```
def describeFuncRet(func):
    def wrapper(*func_args, **func_kwargs):
        print(func(*func_args,**func_kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

Comment: Will this chain properly if I were to run multiply(subtract(add(1,2),add(3,4)),9)?  Instead of using print(...) I am using customprinter.print(...)

Comment: @trident please add that example to your question along with expected output :)

Comment: Downvote because this consumes the return value instead of forwarding it